# Allow userinteraction iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

Is is possible to allow the view to be editable (allow user interaction) when a UIActionSheet is in view? For example `[nameofactionsheet showInView:self.view];`. Normally whenever the action sheet is open the user can't play around with view behind it. Is it possible to allow interaction?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you use UIActionSheet.

But you could implement with custom logic perhaps..

- Wrap the UI in your custom view (for showing different choices)
- Add that custom view to your desired view controller's view
- Voila ;)